# How to set an image as the label of a Menu on MacCatalyst with SwiftUI in Ventura 13.3.1

Tags: swift, swiftui, menu, mac-catalyst, macos-ventura

I want to open a dropdown Menu on **macOS** when the user clicks on an Image.

I am using Mac Catalyst Interface: Optimize for Mac.

I was previously able to accomplish this using the `.buttonStyle(.plain)`

Here is the code:

```
Menu {
    Button {
        //action here
    } label: {
        Text("first button")
    }
    Button {
        //action here
    } label: {
        Text("second button")
    }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.arrow.down.circle")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .foregroundColor(Color("SSGreen"))
        .frame(width: scaleForMac(int: 34), height: scaleForMac(int: 34), alignment: .center)
}
.buttonStyle(.plain)
```

Since I upgraded to Ventura 13.3.1 this no longer seems to work. Now I get a tiny down facing arrow and the image does not render.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Am I doing something wrong, how can I continue to achieve the same result of being able to have a custom view trigger a menu?

Tried to create a custom `buttonStyle` and a custom `menuStyle` but did not manage to achieve desired outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Creating the following `MenuStyle`:

```swift
struct DisplayLabelOnMacOSMenuStyle<Label: View>: MenuStyle {
    let label: Label

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Menu(configuration)
                .menuStyle(.borderlessButton)

            label
                .background(Color.white)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
                .hidden(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad || UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone)
        }
    }
}
```

and using it this way

```swift
Menu {
    Button {
        //action here
    } label: {
        Text("first button")
    }
    Button {
        //action here
    } label: {
        Text("second button")
    }
} label: {
    menuLabel()
}
.menuStyle(
    DisplayLabelOnMacOSMenuStyle(label: menuLabel())
)

// ...

@ViewBuilder
private func menuLabel() -> some View {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.arrow.down.circle")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .foregroundColor(Color("SSGreen"))
        .frame(width: scaleForMac(int: 34), height: scaleForMac(int: 34), alignment: .center)
}
```

should allow you to have a similar look and feel as previously, keeping the same behavior on iPhone / iPad, with the following to bear in mind:

- the background of the `Label` is set to white so as not to see behind a potentially transparent `Label`, but you may want to be able to customize your background color
- there is a slight padding issue for the menu elements when clicking on the menu `Label`, this is because the `Menu` appearance is now a small arrow on macOS, not having the same size as the `Label`.

[image: padding issue]